# Prove or disprove the following:

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let K/F be algebraic. Then any $\sigma$ $\in$ Emb (K/F) induces an automorphism of K.

(Emb(K/F) means all the embeddings of K $\rightarrow$ A (an algebraic closed field) over F. )

I have in mind a counterexample, but i don't know whether it is indeed correct or not.

Consider $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $ \mathbb Q$, and the embedding $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb C$, $\sqrt[3]{2} \rightarrow \sqrt[3]{2} \omega$.  $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $ \mathbb Q$ is algebraic, but the embedding does not induce an automorphism.

Comment: What are your ideas ?
What is $Emb(K/F)$

Comment: @FardadPouran I don't know whether my counterexample is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a correct counterexample. Your first line is true if K/F is "normal" or Galois.

Comment: The assertion is equivalent to $K/F$ being normal. See here : *Algebra, Volume 1 by Lorenz & Levy, page 59*